# Setup SpringBoot in IDEA from Initializr

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I don't understand what happens (before everything worked, feels like I've lost some settings somehow). I download archive from initializer (spring.io; doesn't matter which dependency include, let's say only Spring Web), extract from archive and open project from IDEA. First of all, I'm receiving file ***.iml outside of the container (before it is automatically was created inside)

[image]

Also now I have to Assign to "java" folder MarkDirectoryAs - SourceRoot by hand (before this staff applied authomatcally).
And finally looks like IDEA does not see the itself downloaded dependencies. When the project just opened I receive this:

[image]

How can I fix it?

**UPD**:
Errors after reload

[image]

And Libraries do not have Maven...

[image]

Also what I've found out, I have an error with link to local repository and do not have link to external (like in previous projects)

[image]

don't know how to fix it.

Also in my Maven only Lifecycle folder presented now.

[image]

Comment: Please try to run "Reload" from Gradle tool window.

Comment: Added one more picture. After pressing reload or update there appears error and nothing changed.

Comment: Also, when I insert new dependancies on pom.xml, it is NOT red colored, so I do not need to reload them... feels like changes in file pom.xml are not visible for application

Comment: Are there any errors/warning in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after running Reload?

Comment: Thank you for attempt to help! The problem is fixed. I've left the comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Maven Home Path choose as shown on the pic. (Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Build Tools->Maven)
[image]